# Objective C - Incorrect cell data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Cut into topic.
I have an array defined and Variable I is declared as follow

```
 @interface KTCBLocationTableViewController () {
   NSArray *deserializedArray;
   int i;
 }
```

It stores data retrieved from a remote database which eventually containing the following data when I used the following code to see the content inside

```
//This line is inside a for-loop
[[deserializedArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"rname"];
```

The result of the above code shows the following data

```
Location A
Location B
Location C
Location D
Location E
Location F
Location G
Location H
```

I was going to put these data into the each cell of UITableView. The following code is used.
This table comes with expandable rows and the following code only shows the section of each row.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell...

if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:indexPath.section])
{
    if (!indexPath.row)
    {
        // first row        
            cell.textLabel.text = [[deserializedArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"rname"]; // only top row showing
            i++;
            if ([expandedSections containsIndex:indexPath.section])
            {
                cell.accessoryView = [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeUp];
            }
            else
            {
                cell.accessoryView = [DTCustomColoredAccessory accessoryWithColor:[UIColor grayColor] type:DTCustomColoredAccessoryTypeDown];
            }

    }
    else
    {
//The remaining of code are not given due to the irrelevance.
```

I discovered that the cells are changing after scolling, Location A might become G or others.

I took a look into the line.

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[deserializedArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"rname"]; // only top row showing
i++;
```

and I think this is where the problem is. However, I do not know how can I "populate" all my data in the array to the cell of each row and make it consistent.

Comment: Why you are using i. use indexPath.row. i++ will increase whenever you reloaddata

Comment: reload data ater UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

Comment: @SunnyShah indexPath.row will not work in collapsible tableview, it will be always staying at 0, using indexPath.section will result in the same as the code I stated above

Comment: What is i? It isn't declared anywhere. If it's an instance variable, the value is going to be a bit screwy.

Comment: Please post how do you calculate 'i'.

Comment: Posted the declaration of I at the beginning of the question.
if I reset i to 0 during the execution, the result will be the same

Comment: I think issue is in `if (!indexPath.row)` condition. When `indexPath.row = 0` then `(!indexPath.row)` will become `YES` in Objective-C. and if `row` is greater than 0 then your else condition will execute. Have you debug the code ?

Comment: @JuniorProgrammer: cellForRowAtIndexPath is called for the *visible* cells, in *any order*, and *repeatedly* when you scroll. You *have to* compute the cell contents from the given indexPath. Incrementing an instance variable and relying on the method being called in a certain order can never work.

Answer (score 0):

Use 'indexPath.row'. Change

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[deserializedArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"rname"]; // only top row showing
```

to

```
cell.textLabel.text = [deserializedArray[indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"rname"]; // only top row showing
```

Comment: Sorry, but I think I said the problem of using indexPath.row in this collapsible tableview (in the comment). Even so, I tried your solution and all the data resulted in Location A

Answer (score 0):

Well, your problem is simple but the solution might be a little complicated. cellForRowAtIndexPath method does not get called in order of indexPath. I would recommend using indexPath.row instead of i even though it wont be easy

Comment: Would you mind seeing the comments on the question area?

Comment: Yeah, I read them. Like Martin R implies, you have to get rid of i. I have used collapsible sections before and I know they can be done with indexPath.section and indexPath.row